# oracle - out sys_refcursor parameter - if no result found then?

Tags: sql, oracle

If I use out sys_refcursor parameter, I'm struggling with if the first cursor has any results.

```
create or replace procedure cursorresults
as 
(cursor1 OUT sys_refcursor
cursor2 OUT sys_Refcursor)
begin
      open cursor1 for
      select * from table1; 

      **if cursor1 has any results**

          open cursor2 for
          select * from table2; 
 end;
```

I can requery the table1 to see if there was a match but there must be a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to determine whether a cursor returns results is to attempt to fetch results from the cursor.  Of course, since a cursor is a forward-only structure, that means that you would need to close and re-open the cursor.

It seems very odd, though, that you would only want to open the second cursor if the first cursor returns results.  Are you sure that you don't want to join the two tables, union them, or do something else to combine the two results?

Comment: I have two out sys_refcursor parameters. The example that comes to my mind is open cursor1 for select * from article where articleid = someparameter; open cursor2 for select * from comments where articleid = someparameter;

Comment: @user1831003 - That seems like a classic case where it would make much more sense to join the two tables and return both in a single cursor.  Barring that, just open and return two cursors.  If there are no articles, there will be no comments (presumably).  The caller would attempt to fetch articles, find none, and then could skip fetching from the comments cursor.

Comment: maybe I am understanding it wrong : if I do a join, then won't each row in sys_refcursor look like "articleid, ENTIRE ARTICLE, commentid, etc" being repeated for each comment? One more thing: if I fetch a sys_Refcursor and then reopen it, does it mean I would have to redo the select to refill data into the cursor?